# PL/SQL Convert XML TO XLS

Tags: xml, plsql, xls

I'm creating a `.xlm` file with my Procedure which I save as `myFile.xsl`.

I'm getting an error like this if I try to open `myFile.xls`:

> Error: The file format and extension of don't match

After I press the "Yes" button to Keep opening the file everyting is right and work fine.

**Am I doing something wrong while saving?**

Comment: XLS is probably associated with Microsoft Excel, which is probably opening the file, detects that it doesn't contain an Excel spreadsheet, shows the error, then interprets the file the best way it knows how.

Comment: What happens if you name the file `.xlsx` instead?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp If I do this, I'll get an error like "Cannot open the file is corrupted"

Comment: What extension do you actually use and what kind of files are you handling? In a nutshell: `.xml`: generic XML; possibly Excel 2003 xml file; `.xlm`: Excel (pre-2007) Macro file. This contains an automated interaction with Excel; `.xsl`: XSLT file. Syntactically an xml file. Contains specialized vocabulary, namely a declarative code to specify a transformation between xml vocabularies. `.xls`: Excel Spreadsheet (pre-2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of the actual code, but what I think happens is that it just opens the file, even though the name + extension doesn't match.
From what you wrote:

> ... which I save as myFile.**xsl**.
>
> I'm getting an error like this if I try to open myFile.**xls**

I see a clear mismatch and based on that and considering the title of this:

> PL/SQL Convert XML TO XLS

I'm not really sure what you try to achieve.
If you're creating an [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/WhatIsXSL.html), out of a XML, that's one thing,
but if you create an Excel Spread Sheet (XLS) with it, that's another story.

In all cases - if your program creates XSL files (Excel), then just correct the output extension, if there's something else, please paste the code and/or explain better what you would like to achieve with it.

Cheers